# Does convergence in Lp imply convergence of p-expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $\mathcal{L}^p$, $p$ an integer. Does $EX_n^p$ converge to $EX^p$?

Given epsilon, we have at least $$|EX_n^p - EX^p|  \le E| X_n^p - X^p|$$
but then I am unsure what more I can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that by Hölder's inequality, for each $1\leqslant j\leqslant p$, we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb E\left(\left|X_n -X\right|^j\left|X\right|^{p-j}  \right)=0$. Now, we can conclude  using the expansion $$X_n^p=\left(X_n-X+X\right)^p =\sum_{j=0}^p\binom pj\left(X_n-X\right)^jX^{p-j}=X^p+\sum_{j=1}^p\binom pj\left(X_n-X\right)^jX^{p-j}.$$

Comment: Man, how do you come up with these tricks? Thanks. In hindsight, I guess $p$ being an integer was a clue.